# ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'random' (errno: 15435840)

Tags: 18.04, mysql, database

I'm having trouble creating a database on MySQL. I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu and i was installing MySQL but when i access as a root with:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

And then I tried to create the data base with:

```
CREATE DATABASE random;
```

The thing is that i always get this error:

```
ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'random' (errno: 15435840)
```

I made a search and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719748/error-1006-hy000-cant-create-database-errno-13-mysql-5-6-12) about ERROR 1006 but didn't work for me and then i notice that I'm getting a different message I'm getting the errno: 15435840 and have no clue what to do.

Comment: Did you run [mysql_secure_installation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_secure_installation/) after installation?

Answer (score 0):

I think may be a permissions issue with the MySQL data directory. You could try setting the permissions as follows:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

You can to find out where your data directory is located, from shell/console, type in:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep datadir
```